# Modal pop-up dialog delay

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, popup

In the following code I have been unable to add a delay to the pop-up dialog. I have tried the *setTimeout* function, but I am likely not adding it correctly. Is there a solution?

```
$(function() { 
  var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  if (!getCookie('modalcookie')) {
    overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    $('.popup').show();
  }
```

Comment: The (supplied) code is incomplete (unbalanced curly brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to delay the displaying of the popup then you need to wrap the content of the `if` condition within a `setTimeout()` call:

```
$(function() { 
  var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  if (!getCookie('modalcookie')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      overlay.appendTo(document.body).show();
      $('.popup').show();
    }, 1000); // 1000ms = 1 second delay
  }
});
```